# Which input parameter causes NotSupportedException in File.Create() method?

Tags: .net-6.0, notsupportedexception

I would like to reproduce NotSupportedException by calling System.IO.File.Create method but I haven't found a proper input parameter.

Target framework: .NET 6.0